# AES_128_CTR encryption by openssl and PyCrypto

Tags: python, encryption, openssl, aes, pycrypto

Wondering the right way to convert a AES_128_CTR encryption by openssl to PyCrypto.

First, I did an encryption by openssl as following:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-ctr -in input.mp4 -out output.openssl.mp4 -K 7842f0a1ebc38f44e3e0c81943f68582 -iv d01f40dfc8ec8cd9
```

And then, I tried to do the same thing through PyCrypto:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util import Counter
key = '7842f0a1ebc38f44e3e0c81943f68582'
iv = 'd01f40dfc8ec8cd9'

ctr_e = Counter.new(128, initial_value=int(iv, 16))
encryptor = AES.new(key.decode('hex'), AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr_e)

with open('output.pycrypto.mp4', 'wb') as fout:
    with open('input.mp4', 'rb') as fin:
        fout.write(encryptor.encrypt(fin.read()))
```

I assume they are supposed to be similar, but it is not:

```
diff output.openssl.mp4 output.pycrypto.mp4
Binary files output.openssl.mp4 and output.pycrypto.mp4 differ
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenSSL behaves as expected (fortunately, as documentation to this fact is missing for the command line) and uses the given IV as leftmost bytes of a big endian counter. In other words, the bytes given are the *most significant* part of the 16 byte counter. The code in the question uses the IV as initial counter value, i.e. it is interpreted as the *least significant* part of the counter.

Now it took me some time to fix the Python code as there are two problems with the `Counter` class I had to work around:

- the size of the counter should be 64 bit instead of 128 bit if a prefix of 8 bytes is used; this is a design feature, but it may cause overflow if the amount of bits reserved for the counter is small (it's OK with the current setting of 64 bit though)
- the default initial counter value is set to 1 while CTR mode always starts counting at 0; this is likely an off-by-one bug in the Counter design

So without further ado:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util import Counter

key = '7842f0a1ebc38f44e3e0c81943f68582'.decode('hex')
iv = 'd01f40dfc8ec8cd9'.decode('hex')

ctr_e = Counter.new(64, prefix=iv, initial_value=0)
encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr_e)

with open('output.pycrypto.mp4', 'wb') as fout:
    with open('input.mp4', 'rb') as fin:
        fout.write(encryptor.encrypt(fin.read()))
```

Comment: Really appreciate your description, especially well mentioning of two major problems in my usage of `Counter` class.

Comment: Actually that's not what I meant. There are two problems with the Counter class in general, not so much your usage of it... I'll put it in present tense...

Comment: What a relief to see your comment~

Comment: Forgot the security advice... Important note: using a static nonce (the first or total part of the counter in the code) for the same key and multiple messages (video's) is *unsafe to the extreme*. Normally you should use unique key/IV pairs, *especially* for stream ciphers and stream modes such as CTR.